# No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString. c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, servicio

Tengo un servicio windows que me genera estos errores ya verifique mis cadenas de conexion y estan correctas no se que pase?

> No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString.
>
> El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'C:\log_alert.txt'
>   porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.

```html
        private SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;User ID= xx;Password=******;Initial Catalog=ReportesDB;Server=xxx");
        public string mensaje;
        private List<EntityAlerta> objReporte;
        private System.Timers.Timer timerprocess = null;
```

```html
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Log1("Se inicia servicio " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            timerprocess = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timerprocess.Interval = 800;
            timerprocess.Elapsed += Timerprocess_Elapsed;
            timerprocess.Enabled = true;
            timerprocess.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timerprocess.Enabled = false;
            Log1("servicio detenido");
        }

        void Timerprocess_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            timerprocess.Enabled = false;
            try
            {
                //metodo();
                Thread libRep = new Thread(EnviaAlerta);
                libRep.Start();
                timerprocess.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                timerprocess.Enabled = true;
                Log1("Entro catch: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                timerprocess.Start();
            }
        }
```

```html
        private void EnviaAlerta()
        {
            try
            {
                Conn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Hora FROM Ejecucion WHERE Reporte = 30", Conn);
                string str = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
                Conn.Close();
                string str2 = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        TimeSpan span;
                        string str3 = str;
                        this.mensaje = "Enviando Alertas...";
                        char[] separator = new char[] { ':' };
                        string[] strArray = str3.Split(separator);
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        DateTime time3 = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, int.Parse(strArray[0]), int.Parse(strArray[1]), int.Parse(strArray[2]));
                        if (time3 > now)
                        {
                            span = (TimeSpan)(time3 - now);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            time3 = time3.AddDays(1.0);
                            span = (TimeSpan)(time3 - now);
                        }
                        Task.Delay(span).Wait();
                        Log1("Inicia Env\x00edo de Correos" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        List<string> list = new List<string>();
                        EnviaCorreo correos = new EnviaCorreo();
                        DataTable table = new DataTable();
                        this.objReporte = new List<EntityAlerta>();
                        table = correos.mailAlertas();
                        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                        {
                            EntityAlerta item = new EntityAlerta
                            {
                                IdReporte = Convert.ToString(row["Id_Reporte"]),
                                CveReporte = Convert.ToString(row["Cve_Reporte"]),
                                Asunto = Convert.ToString(row["Asunto"]),
                                Descripcion = Convert.ToString(row["Descripcion"])
                            };
                            this.objReporte.Add(item);
                        }
                        foreach (EntityAlerta alerta3 in this.objReporte)
                        {
                            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
                            {
                                EntityAlerta alerta = new EntityAlerta();
                                //message.To.Add(new MailAddress("abc@abc.com.mx"));
                                message.To.Add(new MailAddress("abc@abc.com.mx"));
                                message.From = new MailAddress("abc@abc.com.mx");
                                message.Subject = alerta3.Asunto.ToString().Trim();
                                message.Body = alerta3.Descripcion.ToString().Trim();
                                message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
                                {
                                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                                    Port = 0x24b,
                                    EnableSsl = true,
                                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@abc.com.mx", "Temporal123")
                                };
                                try
                                {
                                    client.Send(message);
                                    message.Dispose();
                                    Log1("Correos Enviados " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                                }
                                catch (Exception exception)
                                {
                                    Log1(string.Concat(new object[] { "ERROR ", exception.Message, " ", exception.InnerException, " ", exception.Data }));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception2)
                    {
                        Log1(exception2.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Log1("Catch finally: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Conn.Close();
                Conn.Dispose();
            }
   
        }
```

```html
        private void Log1(string mensaje)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"C:\log_alert.txt"))
            {
                writer.Write("r\nLog Entry : ");
                writer.WriteLine("   :");
                writer.WriteLine("   :{0}", mensaje);
                writer.WriteLine("----------------------");
                
            }
        }
```

```html
        public DataTable mailAlertas()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnStr"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT Id_Reporte,Cve_Reporte,Asunto,Descripcion FROM Alertas WHERE Activo = 1";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Close();

            DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
            using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                a.Fill(t1);
            }


            return t1;
        }
```

Comment: en que linea exactamente te lanza ese error?

Comment: ¡Pregunta! ¿while (true)? ¿por qué? ¿en qué momento rompes/sales de ese bucle?

Comment: No veo al provider, algo como proviederName="System.data.SqlClient".  En el método mailAlertas utilizas el connection string que está en la configuración. Porque no utilizas lo mismo. Como esta en tu archivo de configuracion. Salvo que aquí este el problema.

Comment: El problema de mensaje  del archivo se log, es porque estás utilizándolo desde distintos threads y no tiene un mecanismo de sincronización.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

todas las cadenas de conexion se agregan al app.config de la aplicacion y usan con `COFIGUTATIONMANAGER`

> SqlConnection conn = new
>   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnStr"].ConnectionString);

app.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnStr" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;User ID= xx;Password=******;Initial Catalog=ReportesDB;Server=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Pero haces una excepción  aqui: private SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;User ID= xx;Password=******;Initial Catalog=ReportesDB;Server=xxx");

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich esa cadena ya la sustitui con la cadena que muestro en la respuesta y ahora la obtengo desde el app.config

Comment: El error en que línea exactamente ocurre?